# Function to generate Friendly URL Strings is not removing Commas

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I have this function that returns me an friendly url string.

```
public static function getUrlFriendlyString($str) {
       // convert spaces to '-', remove characters that are not alphanumeric
       // or a '-', combine multiple dashes (i.e., '---') into one dash '-'.
       $_str = preg_replace("[-]", "-", preg_replace("[^a-z0-9-]", "",
          strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $str))));
       return substr($_str, 0, 40);
    }
```

Anyway, if I have for example this String:

```
"Product with vitamins, protein, and a lot of good stuff"
```

The resulting string is:

```
"product-with-vitamins,-protein,-and-a-lot-of-good-stuff"
```

As you can see it doesn't remove the commas from the string :/ and my knowledge about regular expressions is `null`.

Comment: Why are you replaceing `[-]` with `-`? That doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't know :S I actually took this function from a tutorial and made some minor changes to avoid using deprecated functions :S

Comment: Also if you convert spaces to dashes AND then remove non alphanumeric characters your dashes are gone! So this makes no sense

Comment: It's not **clear** on what you want to achieve here.

Comment: you could just use urlencode()

Comment: @hwnd make it remove the commas?

Comment: Try `return substr($_str.replace(",", ""), 0, 40)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the delimiters around the regexp, so it used `[` and `]` as the delimiters. As a result, they weren't being treated as the character class operators.

If you want to compress multiple `-` into one, the regexp is `/-+/`, not `[-]`.

```
public static function getUrlFriendlyString($str) {
   // convert spaces to '-', remove characters that are not alphanumeric
   // or a '-', combine multiple dashes (i.e., '---') into one dash '-'.
   $_str = preg_replace("/-+/", "-", preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]/", "",
      strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $str))));
   return substr($_str, 0, 40);
}
```